# Firebase Analytics Screen views and custom events not tracking on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

I have integrated the Firebase Analytics into my app to track user events and behaviors. If we want to track custom screen views and pages used by users in android, how to handle those. if I use  setCurrentScreen with the screen name and the class of the activity or fragment in which the screen view is taking place in code level, but it will resemble in events in Firebase Analytics Dashboard. And setCurrenScreen method was deprecated in android. What will be the alternative for setCurrentScreen for android kotlin.

I have tried these steps:

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")

firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("CATEGORY", "Dispatch")
bundle.putString("ACTION", "Update_Dispatch")
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle)

firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics
firebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "Dashboard_Activity", null )
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "id")
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "DashBoardActivity")
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "DashboardActivity")
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle)
```